# TextField input not working

Tags: actionscript-3

I am working on a class similar to the standard text field. I actually use the default TextField inside it. My only problem is that the textField does not work correctly. If I set it to textField.type = TextFieldType.INPUT, I can delete the text, but I can't enter new text. Also, the cursor is not being displayed. This is my Class (part of it): http://pastebin.com/LsgQjxpa

The skin is like this: http://pastebin.com/yDhEGHLm

I can't figure out what exactly I am doing wrong. I also have to mention that I am compiling for AIR Mobile and testing directly from Flash Builder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem appears to be that you have set the `selectable` property to `false`.  This makes sense when `type` is `TextFieldType.DYNAMIC`. However, it's problematic when the `type` is `TextFieldType.INPUT`.

When you disable selection of the text, no cursor is displayed. I am able to still edit the text. However, since the cursor is not visible I cannot change it's position and the text gets added in front of any existing text.

Comment: Thanks! This actually makes sense. Also, it seems to fix the problem :)